# ionic2 - Device Motion returning observable but unsubscribe gives error

Tags: angular, cordova-plugins, ngcordova, ionic2

I am trying to detect motion using ionic2.
Here is the snippet of my detectMotion.ts.

```
import {DeviceMotion} from 'ionic-native';
@Page({
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/pedometer/pedometer.html'
})
export class Pedometer {
   platform;
   watch;
   constructor () {
        this.platform = platform;
   }
   startWatching() {
       console.log('Starting to watch');
       this.watch = DeviceMotion.watchAcceleration(this.options);
       this.watch.subscribe(result => {this.detectMotion(result)});
   }
   stopWatching() {
       console.log('Stop Watching');
       // this.watch.dispose();
       this.watch.unsubscribe();
       // this.watch.clearWatch();
   }
   detectMotion(result) {
       console.log('Current Readings: '+ JSON.stringify(result) );
       //.....do something with the results.....
       this.stopWatching(); // Stop and wait for a second before restarting
       setTimeout(this.startWatching(), 1000);
   }
}
```

StartWatching is being called on a button click in the html.
I have tried all 3 options that i could research on viz. unsubscribe; dispose; clearWatch
But all in vain. The exact error that i have been getting is

```
error    ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Object #<Observable> has no method 'unsubscribe'
```

from the [reference](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/Device%20Motion/) of ioni2 i learn that it returns a Observable

Any help or pointer is appreciated
Thanks in advance

~Dhaval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you should store the `subscription` returned from the `subscribe` call, and call `unsubscribe()` to that.

You will get something like this:

```
export class Pedometer {
   platform;
   watch;
   watchSub : Subscription;
   constructor () {
        this.platform = platform;
   }
   startWatching() {
       console.log('Starting to watch');
       this.watch = DeviceMotion.watchAcceleration(this.options);
       this.watchSub = this.watch.subscribe(result => {this.detectMotion(result)});
   }
   stopWatching() {
       console.log('Stop Watching');
       // this.watch.dispose();
       this.watchSub.unsubscribe();
       // this.watch.clearWatch();
   }
   detectMotion(result) {
       console.log('Current Readings: '+ JSON.stringify(result) );
       //.....do something with the results.....
       this.stopWatching(); // Stop and wait for a second before restarting
       setTimeout(this.startWatching(), 1000);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @PierreDuc - I was following [this](http://www.gajotres.net/detecting-device-motion-with-ionic-framework-and-ngcordova/) which ioinic1 version. Had a understanding that watch is the handle to subscribe and unsubscribe. Thanks once again it did help me